# how can I get a rectangle from my binary image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I have a binary image ,like this [image]

I want to get a rectangle from the white area which contain all the white area.Any help,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

here what I got using findContours and approxPoly : 
[image: Result]

And here the quick code I wrote :

```
img =  cv2.imread("rectangle.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.astype(np.uint8), 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]

epsilon = 0.05*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon,True)

mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)
for i in range(len(approx)-1):
    start = tuple(approx[i][0])
    end = tuple(approx[i+1][0])
    cv2.line(mask,start,end,255,2)

start = tuple(approx[-1][0])
end = tuple(approx[0][0])
cv2.line(mask,start,end,255,2)
```

Comment: So what is your defects mean?

Comment: Nothing, I just removed it.

Comment: But,When I draw lines on my original image,The white area are not all contain inner the area.as following:

Comment: do you want to do that for only this image or you have different images with different shapes of rectangles?

Comment: different images with different shapes of rectangles

Comment: ah so you're not really looking for a rectangle ? (Also I think it's better if you edit your question and remove your answers ^^)

Comment: @Gpwner please, do not create answers for posting images of what you want, edit your question instead. @ pensfute if you have similar answers that but differ only in something, is better to merge them and have one. for the people to find the correct answer faster :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for a real rectange :

[image: Result]

```
img =  cv2.imread("rectangle.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.astype(np.uint8), 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]

epsilon = 0.05*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon,True)

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)
for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
    cv2.line(img,start,end,[255,0,0],2)
    #cv2.circle(img,far,5, [255,0,0],-1)



cv2.imwrite("img_semRect.png", img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Thanks anyway!I think I don't make my question clear.Sorry for that .I want a rectange which can contain all the white area .That is say: